# How to use 'exists' quantifier?

Tags: dafny

The Dafny documentation doesn't go through using 'exists' quantifiers.

```
method Main() {
    assert (exists n: int :: n > 1);
}
```

This comes up with an AssertionError

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
predicate dummy(n: int) {true}

method Main() {
    assert dummy(2);
    assert (exists n : int {:trigger dummy(n)} :: n > 1);
}
```

You can replace `dummy(2)` with `dummy(m)` for any integer `m > 1`.

This answer isn't great, since I can't tell you exactly why the above works. However, for more information on triggers you can read [this](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ#how-does-dafny-handle-quantifiers-ive-heard-about-triggers-what-are-those).